# How to get sharedpreference value from normal java class android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am storing email address in sharedpreference once user is logged in. and i am accessing that sharedpreference activity into every activity. that's fine. but when i try to access shared preference variable into any normal class (non-activity) its giving error[image]

i am calling MyLocationReceiver class from MainActivity..

```
private PendingIntent getPendingIntent() {
    Intent intent=new Intent(Home.this,MyLocationReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(MyLocationReceiver.ACTION);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSharedPreferences` needs a Context. You already have the `context` as a parameter in the method `onReceive(context, intent)`.

Therefore, just replace the `getSharedPreferences` line with the following

```
context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0)
```

Comment: how to pass content from pendingintent method i have mentioned that method in question..

Comment: Alright, updated the Answer, I am sorry I totally missed that the `onReceive` has a `Context` parameter, which you have to use in order to access the `Shared Preferences` from the `BroadcastReceiver`